# getting text value using xpath with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping

```
from lxml import html
import requests
url = 'https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND'
page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
num = tree.xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/section[2]/div[1]/div/section[1]/section/section[2]/section/div[1]/span[1]/text()')
print (num)
```

this is the code I have written. I'm trying to get the string 2758.82,from [this](https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SPX:IND). but what I get is.

```
[]
```

I copied the xpath for that section from the website. I have seen similar questions here, but they didn't help. Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: If you still didn't get the number you wised to parsed, there is one more thing you need to do other than what @Arount has already suggested. You need to define a header like `requests.get(url,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})` to make your scraper more like a human.

Comment: Thanks!! It's working now.

Comment: one more thing..how do I access something like `<div style="display:inline" data-dobid="dfn"><span>some text.</span></div>` and what if `<span>` has some attributes too?

Comment: If you wanna play with the visible tags, try using selenium which will let you parse whatever items you want to grab considering their visible form.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about the xpath. It's about how the page is generated.

If you check the content of `page.content` you will see there is no `<div id="root" [..]>` in the webpage's source.
It's because the HTML content is mainly generated via Javascript.

But this is not something that should stop you, if you open the raw html source (from `page.content`) and look for the value you want (2759.81), you will find a tag: `<meta itemprop="price" content="2759.82" />` and another `<div class="price">2759.81</div>`, you can use one of them:

```
print(tree.xpath('//*[@itemprop="price"]')[0].get('content'))
```

Gives

```
2759.82
```

Comment: Thanks!!.. and what do you mean by from `page.content`? should I look for `<meta itemprop="price" content="2759.82" />` in actual page source? because when I print `page.content` I get some unaligned HTML text and I can't find `<meta itemprop="price" content="2759.82" />` there....also...when I try to execute the code you suggested....I get `IndexError: list index out of range
`